# How to capitalize first character of each word in a string?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I came across a problem statement where I had to capitalize the first char in a sentence and the subsequent char of the words that follow. I came up with a solution using regex but I had to use two regular expressions to get the work done.

Is there a way of combining these two regex expressions into one?

```
import re
def capitalize(string):
    l2 = re.findall(r'([^\d][a-zA-Z]+\w*)', string) # reg exp1 
    l4 = re.findall(r'(^[a-zA-Z]+\w*)', string) # reg exp2 
    #  Is there a way of combining these? 
    if l4 not in l2:
        l2.extend(l4)
    l3 = {e: e.title() for e in l2}
    newstring = string
    for item in l3:
        newstring = newstring.replace(item, l3[item])
    return newstring


validatorvalue = 'q w e r  G H J  K  M' # => o/p  'Q W E R  G H J  K  M'
# validatorvalue = 'hello   world  lol' => o/p  'Hello   World  Lol'
# validatorvalue = "1 w 2 r 3g"   => "1 W 2 R 3g"
print(capitalize(validatorvalue))
```

I had to stick with both these regex, as this was the only way the above 2 test cases would pass the criteria.

Comment: These patterns make no sense to me.  Also never start variables with lower case l

Comment: It seems to me you can use [`re.sub(r'\b[a-z]', lambda x: x.group().upper(), validatorvalue)`](http://rextester.com/MJCPC32320)

Comment: Or, in the above example, use `(?<!\S)[a-z]` if you only want to match a lowercase ASCII letter preceded with whitespace or at the start of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capitalize all the words in a sentence, you can use `re.sub` and `re.findall`:

```
import re
def capitalize_string(s):
  return re.sub('(?<=^)[a-z]|(?<=\s)[a-z]', '{}', s).format(*map(str.upper, re.findall('(?<=^)[a-z]|(?<=\s)[a-z]', s)))

strings = ['q w e r  G H J  K  M', 'hello   world  lol', "1 w 2 r 3g"]
result = list(map(capitalize_string, strings))
```

Output:

```
['Q W E R  G H J  K  M', 'Hello   World  Lol', '1 W 2 R 3g']
```

Comment: @Abhishek `(?<=^)` is a positive lookbehind, which means that the following pattern, in this case `[a-z]`, will only match the input if `[a-z]` occurs at the start of the string.

Comment: @Ajax1234 what's the difference between `(?<=^)` and `^`?

Comment: And in this case, you are checking for both the conditions (?<=^)[a-z]|(?<=\s)[a-z], the begining and whenever there is a space. | being an or. hope my understanding is correct?

Comment: @Abhishek That is correct. `|` will attempt to match either of the expressions.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Abhishek Glad to help!

Comment: nice usage of regex +1

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Thank you.

Comment: Note that `(?<!\S)` matches in the two situations (at the start of the string or if the position is preceded by a whitespace). Using it, you can avoid the alternation in your pattern.

Answer (score 9):

You can get the same result *without using `regex`*. Python has [**`str.title()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) which does the same. For example:

```
>>> 'q w e r  G H J  K  M'.title()
'Q W E R  G H J  K  M'

>>> 'Hello   world  lol'.title()
'Hello   World  Lol'

>>> '1 w 2 r 3g'.title()
'1 W 2 R 3G'
```

OR you may use [**`string.capwords()`**](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string.capwords) which does the similar operation. For example:

```
>>> import string

>>> string.capwords('q w e r  G H J  K  M')
'Q W E R G H J K M'       # ^^ Multiple white space was replaced with single space 

>>> string.capwords('Hello   world  lol')
'Hello World Lol'

>>> string.capwords('1 w 2 r 3g')
'1 W 2 R 3g'
```

**Note:** As mentioned in [`string.capwords()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string.capwords) document:

> **If the optional second argument sep is absent or None, runs of whitespace characters are replaced by a single space and leading and trailing whitespace are removed,** otherwise sep is used to split and join the words.

---

As an alternative, you may write your custom function to firstly split the string based on space to get list of words, then capitalize each word using [`str.capitalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize), and finally join back your list to get the desired string. Here's a sample example:

```
def convert_string(my_str):
    return ' '.join(s.capitalize() for s in my_str.split())
```

Sample run:

```
>>> convert_string('Q w e r  g h j  k  m')
'Q W E R G H J K M'
>>> convert_string('Hello   world  lol')
'Hello World Lol'
>>> convert_string('1 w 2 r 3g')
'1 W 2 R 3g'
```

Comment: That's pretty neat as well! Thank you,

Answer (score 7):

The `title` method does this.

```
>>> my_string='hello world i need some capital letters'
>>> my_string.title()
'Hello World I Need Some Capital Letters'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Moinuddin's non-regex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49589711/3832970) in case you want to capitalize "words" that are space separated.

In case there are words glued to punctuation and they also need to be capitalized you may use

```
re.sub(r'\b[a-z]', lambda x: x.group().upper(), validatorvalue)
```

See the [Python online demo](http://rextester.com/MJCPC32320). The `\b` matches a word boundary and `[a-z]` matches a lowercase ASCII letter.

Or, to extend it to all Unicode letters,

```
re.sub(r'\b[^\W\d_]', lambda x: x.group().upper(), validatorvalue)
```

In Python 2, you need to pass the `re.U` modifier to make `\W` and `\d` shorthand character classes Unicode-aware.